# Java 8: Efficient way to Collect elements as TreeMap from List

Tags: java, optimization, java-8

I have a `Student` object as below

```
class Student{
    String name,email,country;
    //getters setters
}
```

And I need collect the elements as `TreeMap<String,List<String>>` where key is student's `country` and value is the list of `email`

```
Map<String, List<Student>> countryStudents = students.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getCountry));
Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        countryStudents .entrySet().forEach(entry -> map.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue().stream().map(student -> student .getEmail()).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Am wondering if is there any efficient way to do this instead of doing it in 2 iterations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupingBy` collector along with `mapping` collector to do it in one pass. Here's how it looks.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = students.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getCountry, TreeMap::new, 
        Collectors.mapping(Student::getEmail, Collectors.toList())));
```

Alternatively, a much better approach is to use `computeIfAbsent` to construct the map in single pass over the list. If I were you, I would rather use this.

```
Map<String, List<String>> stdMap = new TreeMap<>();
for (Student student : students) 
    stdMap.computeIfAbsent(student.getCountry(), unused -> new ArrayList<>())
        .add(student.getEmail());
```

Comment: I think `unused -> new ArrayList<>()` can be written as `ArrayList::new`